# windows phone GameTimerEventArgs reset xna

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

So I have a game running right now that uses the "e" in: private void OnUpdate(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e) to keep the world speeds updated, however I don't know how to reset this GameTimerEventArgs for when I restart the game (without actually exiting the game)

this is how I use it

```
  worldSpeed = (float)(3 + e.TotalTime.TotalMilliseconds / 10000);
```

suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query `GameTimerEventArgs.ElapsedTime` each frame. Ignore `TotalTime`.

Accumulate the elapsed time in a variable. This way you can reset the variable to zero when you restart the game. You can also implement pausing by not accumulating time while paused.

In your case, it looks like you're increasing the `worldSpeed` as gameplay goes on. So rather than accumulate time spent running, you could just accumulate changes to `worldSpeed` like this:

```
if(!paused)
{
    worldSpeed += (float)(e.ElapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds / 10000f);
}
```

And set `worldSpeed` to 3 whenever you restart.